# Rails Active Record: has_many using custom id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activerecord, rspec

I am creating a referral system. My goal is to refer to an object by a unique id rather than a Rails' custom id.

These are my following models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  set_primary_key :user_id
  has_many :referral, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: :user_referral
  has_many :referred, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: :user_referred
end

class Referral < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_referral, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user_referred, class_name: 'User'
end
```

These are my ActiveRecord tables:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :user_id, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateReferrals < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :referrals do |t|
      t.references :user_referral, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }, null: false
      t.references :user_referred, foreign_key: { to_table: 'users' }, null: false
      t.string :user_email, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So for example, I want to be able to do calls such as:

```
    User.create!(
      first_name: 'A',
      last_name: 'B',
      email: '123@test.com',
      user_id: 'userA'
    )
    User.create!(
      first_name: 'C',
      last_name: 'D',
      email: '456@test.com',
      user_id: 'userB'
    )
    Referral.create!(
      user_email: 'user1@test.com',
      user_referral: 'userA',
      user_referred: 'userB'
    )
```

However, 'user_referral' and 'user_referred' ids are not accepted. Any way to fix this? Much appreciated

Comment: Rails will automatically add a unique ":id" column implicitly when creating a table and I highly recommend you use it. The user_id column should be on the Referral table and if you set your relationships in the models appropriately it will automagically look at user_id when querying. You're breaking rails conventions for what looks to be no gain but potential headaches when trying to user rails helper methods from relationships.  User has_many referrals, referrals belongs_to user, use the standard ids and you're done.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As you already noticed not using the table's primary key is against Rails' conventions and much harder to implement. Is it worth the hassle? What do you try to archieve?

Comment: I think for the `foreign_key` option you have to pass `user_referrel_id` - the foreign key references a field not an association

Comment: what max said + `user_referral: 'userA'` it should be either `user_referral_id:` or `userA` should be an object, not a string . `t.references :user_referral` should create a `user_referal_id` column i think

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with declaring a table with a non-standard primary key:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: :string, primary_key: :user_id do |t|
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You then need use the correct type for the foreign key columns and make sure they point to the correct column on users since the default is `id`.

```
class CreateReferrals < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :referrals do |t|
      t.references :user_referral, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: 'users', primary_key: :user_id }, 
        null: false, 
        type: :string
      t.references :user_referred, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: 'users', primary_key: :user_id }, 
        null: false, 
        type: :string
      t.string :user_email, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Congratulations! You just made a godawful mess out of the most trivial problem.

Comment: Appreciate the help, pretty new to Rails. Though i'm getting an error of "you can't redefine the primary key column 'broker_id'. To define a custom primary key, pass { id: false } to create_table"

Comment: I would really recommend you stop whatever you're doing and learn the rails conventions instead - your making it needlessly hard on yourself.